# What can i get from the lua bytecode retrivied via string.dump()?

Tags: lua, luajit

I’m using lua + luajit 2.0.4 and I’m wondering - Is it possible to restore the original parts of the code from the dumps of lua functions?

```lua
function a(l) 
  if l > 3 then
    print(l*l)
  end
end

local b = string.dump(a)
```

In this example, I am doing the `string.dump` of the 'a' function, and here I come to the questions like:

1. Is it possible to write this dump into a .txt file?
2. Is it possible to get the original names of functions, variables, and upvalues?
3. Is it possible to get strings, numbers, tables?
4. Is it possible to restore it to the full code, and if not, is it possible to get a disassembled listing?

Answer (score 1):

"Yes" to all questions with a couple of caveats. For (1), make sure that "b" is used as part of the "mode" parameter in `io.open` on Windows, as the output of `string.dump` will have some binary content. For (2), it's only true when `string.dump` is used without the `strip` option, which was [added in LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/extensions.html):

> string.dump(f [,strip])
>
> An extra argument has been added to string.dump(). If set to true,
>   'stripped' bytecode without debug information is generated. This
>   speeds up later bytecode loading and reduces memory usage.

For (4), I found this document to be very useful: http://files.catwell.info/misc/mirror/lua-5.2-bytecode-vm-dirk-laurie/lua52vm.html (it's for Lua 5.2, but most of the content applies to LuaJIT as well); it also include a section on the difference between full and stripped bytecode that may answer some of your questions.